What does $\cos^2x$ mean? (only the 2 is an exponent)
What does the expression $\cos^2x$ mean? For context, the 2 is the exponent, and the $x$ is not in superscript.
$$I=I_0\cos^2\theta$$
The above equation shows the context I'm looking for. If you isolate $\cos^2\theta$, when solving for $\theta$ would you $cos^{-1}$ both sides or square root first?

Does this answer your question? Why is $\cos(x)^2$ written as $\cos^2(x)$?

I believe that $\cos^2(x)$ likely means $(\cos(x))^2$ in this context. A source of confusion might be that the inverse trigonometric function $\arccos(x)$ is often notated as $\arccos(x) = \cos^{-1}(x) \ne (\cos(x))^{-1}$.
To solve, $(\cos(\theta))^2 = \frac{l}{l_0}$ yields the two branches $\cos(\theta) = \pm \sqrt{\frac{l}{l_0}}$, after which you'll need to consider the periodicity of cosine to get all solutions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions

Ah ok, that clears it up

It means the same as $(cos x)^2$.
To solve for $\theta$ you would have to square root first.
